# Value matching under sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, matching, sparklyr

I tried value matching under sparklyr using:

```
spark_parquet %>% filter(customer_id %in% spark_unique_customer_ids)
```

However, I received the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("escape") : no applicable method for 'escape' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_spark', 'tbl_sql', 'tbl_lazy', 'tbl')"
```

Any suggestions how to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to use `semi_join`:

```
spark_parquet <- copy_to(
  sc, 
  tibble(customer_id = c(1, 2, 3), value = c(-1, 0, 1))
)
spark_unique_customer_ids <- copy_to(sc, tibble(customer_id = c(1, 3)))

spark_parquet %>% semi_join(spark_unique_customer_ids, by = "customer_id")
```

```
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 2]
  customer_id value
*       <dbl> <dbl>
1           1    -1
2           3     1
```

although SQL API should work as well:

```
spark_parquet %>%  sdf_register("spark_parquet")
spark_unique_customer_ids %>% sdf_register("spark_unique_customer_ids")

sc %>% spark_session() %>% 
  invoke(
    "sql", 
    "SELECT * FROM spark_parquet 
     WHERE customer_id IN (
       SELECT customer_id FROM spark_unique_customer_ids)") %>% 
   sdf_register()
```

```
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 2]
  customer_id value
*       <dbl> <dbl>
1           1    -1
2           3     1
```